# Django templates: how do I use key to access value?

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

I don't want to iterate through the dictionary.  I have a key, and simply want to return the value for that key if it exists.

I'm not getting any results.

```
users // a dictionary of user_ids and values
user.key // a user id.

{{ users.user.key }}
```

This displays nothing when I know the value for the key passed exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Django interprets `users.user.key` as `users.user[key]`, which of course is not what you want.

You can use `with` directive to work around this.

```
 {% with user.key as user_key %}
    {{users.user_key}} 
 {% endwith %}
```

Comment: I'm on GAE which has Django 0.96 I think, and that's not working.  Maybe I need to create a custom filter.

Comment: For what it is worth this does not actually look like it works for Django 1.4.x. I've been told that this is not something that is supported. If this works it must require some additional filter that is not listed as a part of this answer.